# How to correct maxmind GeoIP location?

Tags: geoip, maxmind

my tunnelbroker (HE) IPv6 prefix is located at IRAN maxmind GeoIP says.

My Prefix is: 2001:470:7549::/48 and should be reported in US. How can i correct this?

Greetings

Answer (score 0):

The link in julienc's answer is no longer valid.

Data corrections can be submitted to MaxMind with the following links:

- [Correct your location](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-location-correction)
- [Correct network information](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-isp-org-correction)
- Email correction@maxmind.com to correct other kinds of data